# Where did the "WP-Custom" plugin go?

Tags: plugins

There used to be a plugin called "WP-Custom" in Wordpress plugin base. Does anyone know what its new name or where I can get it? Wordpress shows no sign left of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [author's website](http://kovshenin.com/wordpress/plugins/wp-custom/), the plugin has been removed as it is no longer beneficial when custom post types are available.

However, if you are so inclined, you can download it from the above page.